# How to migrate data to remote server with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, data-migration

How can I dump my database schema and data in such a way that the usernames, database names and the schema names of the dumped data matches these variables on the servers I deploy to?

My current process entails moving the data in two steps. First, I dump the schema of the database (`pg_dump --schema-only -C -c`) then I dump out the data with `pg_dump --data-only -C` and restore these on the remote server in tandem using the `psql` command. But there has to be a better way than this.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Have you considered replication instead dump/restore?

Comment: @DwayneTowell I've never done replication. I thought replication was used for multi-server setups. I have just one server for now. Can you give me some direction for where to find resources on this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the following to replicate databases.

```
pg_basebackup -x -P -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data -h OTHER_DB_IP_ADDR -U postgres
```

It requires the "master" server at OTHER_DB_IP_ADDR to be running the replication service and `pg_hba.conf` must allow replication connections. You do not have to run the "slave" service as a hot/warm stand by in order to replicate. One downside of this method compared with a dump/restore, the restore operation effectively vacuums and re-indexes and resets EVERYTHING, while the replication doesn't, so replicating can use a bit more disk space if your database has been heavily edited. On the other hand, replicating is MUCH faster (15 mins vs 3 hours in our case) since indexes do not have to be rebuilt.

Some useful references:

http://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/setup-replication-with-postgres-9-2-on-centos-6redhat-el6fedora/

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/high-availability.html

http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2013/02/16/zero-to-postgresql-streaming-replication-in-10-mins/

Comment: Just want to add, that it is possible (at least now in v11) to pass the entire conninfo string as one command line argument: `pg_basebackup -d 'host=127.0.0.1 port=25432' -D /postgres/data/path`